# In my bot I'm using my command bot info or my bot joins new guild it getting errors to send the message

Tags: discord.js, sharding

When ever I'm using my bot info command it showing this error and i don't know how to solve it

Error

````js
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'broadcastEval')

    at module.exports (/home/container/src/commands/bot/info.js:7:22)

    at Client.client.loadSubcommands (/home/container/src/handlers/functions/functions.js:87:130)

    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)```
````

Comment: Can you add your code as well?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.